# Why does indexed_search don't work only on sub-pages in TYPO3 8 / 9?

Tags: search, typo3, typo3-8.x, indexed

I need your help.
I've a TYPO3-installation (version 8.7.24) with 8 different websites in my tree.
Now I want to install and configure "indexed_search" for every sub-page.
The index is ok and works.

**My page-tree:**

```
- root-page (PID: 1)
-- sub-page-tree 1 (PID: 179)
-- sub-page-tree 2 (PID: 146)
-- sub-page-tree 3 (PID: 502)
-- sub-page-tree ... up to 8
```

Now I want to search on every single sub-page-tree as it's own.

When I set the "plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.rootPidList = 1", the search-form works, but it show every result from every other sub-page-tree. But when I set the "rootPidList = 179", I don't get any results.
I've tried it on another website with TYPO3 v9.5.5 and there's the same problem.

Do you know where the problem could be?

Comment: http://labor.99grad.de/wenn-indexed_search-nicht-indiziert/  has a trick:
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
   _DEFAULT_PI_VARS.sections=rl621_621
   search {
      rootPidList = -1
   }
} Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below `621` is the root-id for instance, I saw this trick [on this site](http://labor.99grad.de/wenn-indexed_search-nicht-indiziert/).

For the author of the article it's not clear why this setting does **NOT** work:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.rootPidList = 621
```

But he had success with this setup:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
   _DEFAULT_PI_VARS.sections=rl621_621
   search {
      rootPidList = -1
   }
}
```

The variable `rl621_621` (rl stands for „RootLevel“), it's used for replacing the marker `###SECTIONS###` in the search template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[_sections]" value="###SECTIONS###">
```

Sidenote:  On the linked page the input-field is really hidden, as the brackets are not replaced by htmlentities, even it should as the html should be visible as part of the article.

Comment: Thank yout for your quick answer.

Is it the same with "Extbast & Fluid"?

The marker in my Template is "<f:form.hidden name="search[_sections]" value="{searchParams.sections}" />".
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = 179 results in "<input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][_sections]" value="179">", but  there are still no results.

_DEFAULT_PI_VARS.sections=rl179_179 or rl2_179 has no impact on my sourcecode.

Comment: My bad, but "plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl2_179" doesn't work either

Comment: That is too bad, I did not test it, the only other thing I can think of is caching somehow in your installation. Some sort of caching? Sry it did not help :)

Comment: It worked.

I was on the wrong rootline-id.
**plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.defaultOptions.sections = rl1_179** AND **plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.rootPidList = -1** worked perfectly.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice to hear :)!